# shutil copiar cuando el destino ya existe

Tags: python

estoy intentando copiar el contenido de una carpeta (directorio) a otra ubicacion donde la misma carpeta ya existe:
ejemplo:

```
Origen  : C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\SPOT\NotProcess\Radiometric\img_spot6_ms_001
Destino : C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\SPOT\Process\img_spot6_ms_001
```

Esto lo estoy intentando con la librería shutil de la siguiente forma

```
origen = carpetaImagenes
destino = pathBase + pathImagesOutPut + "\\" + pathImagen
print(f"Origen  : {origen}")
print(f"Destino : {destino}")
dest = shutil.copytree(origen, destino)
```

pero me esta dando un error.

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:
```

obviamente es porque la carpeta de destino ya existe.

Existe alguna forma de decirle a shutil que sobrescriba el contenido de la carpeta destino??

edit:
Utilice

```
dest = shutil.copy(origen, destino )
```

pero ahora me da un problema :
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: `shutil.copytree()` tiene un argumento `dirs_exist_ok=True` para que no dé error si existe el destino.

Comment: Verificar la documentación: [shutil.copytree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)

Comment: gracias ChemaCortes por el dato. Funciono perfectamente.!!

Comment: "Permission denied". Revisa que tengas permisos de grabación en el directorio y que el archivo a reemplazar no esté protegido.